# My website show incorrect with my description when I search on Google engine

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hello, everybody.

My website is [http://cs2.ftu.edu.vn]. When I search keyword "cs2 ftu" on Google engine. The result is the same in photo

[image]

Please help me fix it !

Comment: It says your site may be hacked when i searched in google.com. Better hire someone from any freelance site and get it corrected. it is not a small task to clean a website affected with malware. Also you need to check this before asking the question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Ok, thank you Amit Ray